# XPath query to get a sub-node depending whether the node name starts with a number or not

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following XML structure:

```
<products>
    <C8TJM>
        <code>C8TJM</code>
        <name>Product</name>
        <description>Product description</description>
    </C8TJM>
    <D75KF>
        <code>D75KF</code>
        <name>Product</name>
        <description>Product description</description>
    </D75KF>
    <_89TJX>
        <code>89TJX</code>
        <name>Product</name>
        <description>Product description</description>
    </_89TJX>
</products>
```

Each sub-node represents a product and the name of the node is the product code. Because XML doesn't allow nodes to start with a number an underscore is automatically added to the name of the node.

I know the product code upfront.

I have to write an XPath query to:

- first check if the product code starts with a number, if it does,
  then prefix it with an underscore;
- search through the tree for that
  product code and get the description.

**Later edit**

Managed to write this variable definition:

```
<xsl:variable name="prefixedProductCode">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains('0123456789', substring($productCode, 1, 1))">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('_', $productCode)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$productCode" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

But I wanted to do it on the fly, in the XPath query, without having to define a new variable.

Comment: Share what you've tried so far

Comment: My XSL knowledge is very limited, so all I know so far is to get the description but without checking for the number: `//products/'+$productCode+'/description`.

Comment: I know that I can use the `starts-with()` function, but I don't know how to integrate it in the query.

Comment: I can suggest you something like `//products/*[number(substring(name(), 0, 2))>=0]` to check whether node name starts with integer

Comment: So it can be done in a single query, without a new variable? I don't know how to continue your example.

Comment: Are you overcomplicating things here? If you know the code, and want to get the description, you can just do `//products/*[code=$productCode]/description`, thus not worrying about the name of the node at all.

Comment: This is a prime example of why XML element names should not contain data. The element name should be `<product>` in all cases, not `<C8TJM>` or the like - this is ludicrous. If you have designed this part of the system, or have any influence over it, I strongly suggest you change this, instead of carrying on with this broken approach.

Comment: @Tomalak, I have no authority in changing the XML structure. I have to use it as presented.

Comment: @TimC, your solution looks cleaner and I believe is faster. I ended up doing something like `//products/node()[name() = $productCode]/description`

Comment: @Cosmin To properly close the thread, post a two-liner answer of your own, and accept it. That's perfectly fine on SO if you have found the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final implementation:

```
//products/node()[name() = $productCode]/description
```